# What is a fast/scalable way to write a RESTful API today?

Tags: web-applications, rest, cloud, scalability

I will be writing a RESTful API soon and am wondering as to which technology lends itself most to making the end product scalable and fast.

Currently I am considering:

- Node.js/Express
- Ruby/Sinatra

Comment: Just watched a video on node.js this weekend. Interesting stuff and seems designed for your fast/scalable needs... Looking at Express, since you mentioned it, it seems to provide the routing that Sinatra was neat for.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you look into the fascinating topic of HTTP caching. It is not so much the server implementation that determines your response performance or server capacity but how you take advantage of cachability ( which is a core rationale behind REST's design).

Remember: the fastest request is that which you do not need to handle but that comes out of a cache. Technologies like edge side includes (ESI) let you split your representations into parts that have different volatily.

On the sever side, use the tools that suits you development process needs.